# mysqli_error not returning anything

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a php script which is supposed to insert a new row to a remote database. Something is not quite working as it should, but when I try to debug with `mysqli_error` it doesn't return anyting. Code as follows:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die("Unable to Connect to '$dbhost'");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$query = "INSERT INTO #DBname.TableName# (Section,Gender,WinningTeam,LosingTeam,FixtureD,FixtureT,Venue,Court,Texts,SetsWon,SetsLost,Winner_Score,Loser_Score) VALUES ($Section,$Gender,$WinningTeam,$LosingTeam,$FixtureD,$FixtureT,$Venue,$Court,$Texts,$SetsWon,$SetsLost,$Winner_Score,$Loser_Score)";              

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
```

The error message says `mysqli_error` expects exactly 1 paramater, 0 was given. However when I replace it with `mysqli_error($connect)` I get *Error 404 - php script not found on server*.

Pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, can anyone help out?

Kind regards

Comment: I missed the single quotes on the values I tried to populate the database with. Thanx to the 2 guys that replied, but if you read the whole question you would have seen I did in fact try mysqli_error($connect) and this was not what caused the issue

Answer (score 1):

function mysqli_error() needs one parameter according to [php.net](http://php.net/mysqli_error)

So in your case:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
```